Vote Early, Vote Often!
Voting is a very important part of Stack Exchange sites.
It's important to vote for the following reasons:

It draws attention to good quality questions and removes attention from poor ones
It encourages participation in the site. New users who receive plenty of votes are more likely to feel part of the community and participate
It eases the burden of site moderation. Because the more votes someone receives the more privileges they gain. This allows others to help with closing, editing etc.

What are some good reasons to vote up a question:

The question has benefited myself and/or is likely to benefit others in the community
In most cases if you think the question is worthwhile to answer it should be worthwhile to vote up
The question is "a good one", it is thought provoking and will provide good quality answers

How often am I voting and how is the site tracking with voting:
You can view the leader-board here https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all where you can see who has cast the most up-votes so far
Continue to support the community and keep voting!

Well said! That's really interesting - I never knew you could see a vote count like that, but glad to see I'm doing well. 
I do think it's weird when I see questions with lots of answers and no votes! Hopefully people will start to realise that being part of the community involves supporting others as well as asking your own questions. 
Thanks for the encouragement, and your dedication to making Chinese.SE a big success :-)

If a question is worth answering, I think we should upvote it.
